# How to get html autocomplete in monaco editor

Tags: vite, monaco-editor

I can't manage to have tag autocomplete for html language like in [this playground demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.36.1#example-creating-the-editor-web-component)

I'm using Vite 4.1.1 and Monaco Editor 0.36.1

Here is my code:

`editor.js`

```js
    import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
    import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/monaco.contribution';
    import 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/basic-languages/html/html.contribution';

    import EditorWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker';
    import HtmlWorker from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker?worker';
    
    self.MonacoEnvironment = {
        getWorker (_, label) {
            if (label === 'html') return new HtmlWorker()
            return new EditorWorker()
        }
    }

    monaco.editor.create( document.getElementById( txtArea.id ), {
            value:           '\n',
            language:        'html',
            automaticLayout: true,
            lineNumbers:     "off",
            minimap:         {enabled: false},
            padding:         { top: 12, right: 15, bottom: 12, left: 15 },
            overviewRulerLanes: 0,
            overviewRulerBorder: false,
            theme:           'vs-dark'
        } );
```

- I don't have any error message in the console
- Syntaxic highlighting works correctly
- It seems `getWorker()` is never fired

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm not using Vue, React or Typescript, just Laravel + Vite, so if someone has a simpler solution...

Answer (score 1):

I've spent 3 days on this.

- I can't make monaco web workers work in my local environment...
- I can't build because of a rollup error...
- etc.

I ended up using AMD version instead of ESM

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.36.1/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({ paths: { vs: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.36.1/min/vs' } });

    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
        monaco.editor.create( document.getElementById( txtArea.id ), {
            value:           '\n',
            language:        'html',
            automaticLayout: true,
            lineNumbers:     "off",
            minimap:         {enabled: false},
            padding:         { top: 12, right: 15, bottom: 12, left: 15 },
            overviewRulerLanes: 0,
            overviewRulerBorder: false,
            theme:           'vs-dark'
        } );
    });
</script>
```